# Does the classical expression for divergence hold for (not continuously) differentiable functions?

Tags: vector-analysis, divergence-operator

The question is simple. I state it for $\mathbb{R}^3$, although I am pretty sure that dimension 3 should not be relevant here.

It is well known that the divergence of a vector field at a point is defined as a limit ratio involving the flux (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Definition) if it exists. Besides, if $F$ is a $\textbf{continuously differentiable}$ vector field $F=(F_1,F_2,F_3)$, the divergence exists and it is given by $$F = \frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial F_{3}}{\partial z}. \quad \quad (*)$$

Assume now that $F$ is differentiable (but not necessarily continuously differentiable). My question is:

1. Does the divergence of $F$ (limit ratio involving the flux) always exist?
2. Provided that the divergence exists, can be always computed via (*) or does it exist a counterexample?

In general, books (or at least the ones that I have checked) just state the result for the continuously differentiable case, but do not tell anything about what happens when only differentiability is required.

Comment: For 1 I am not sure of your claim.

But for 2, I think that the counterexample (if any) can not be that way. Indeed, differentiability implies that if partial derivatives are zero, then any directional derivative is zero. Differentiability (but not continuous differentiability) means that sudden changes in the differential can appear, but only when you move the base point that you are considering. If this point is fixed, the differential makes an estimate of the directional behaviour of your function (locally) in the intuitive way with a better-than-linear error.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake! You are absolutely correct.